# join pysprak data to desire output

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to join two datasets with desire out like below:

DATASET 1:

```text
PIN           LOCATION
1234          Germany
2356          Poland
2894          England
3452          Bloomberg
```

DATASET 2:

```text
MAIL           STARTLOCATION      ENDLOCATION
ami@test.com        1234             2894
asd@test.com        2356             1234
cddv@test.com       3452             2894
```

OUTPUT SHOULD BE:

```text
MAIL           STARTLOCATION      ENDLOCATION  LOCATION1       LOCATION2
ami@test.com        1234             2894       Germany         England
asd@test.com        2356             1234       poland          Germany
cddv@test.com       3452             2894      Bloomberg        England
```

Tried:

```
condi = [((df1.PIN == df2.STARTLOCATION) | (df1.PIN == df2.ENDLOCATION))]

joindata = df1.join(df2, on = condi, how = 'outer').select('*')
```

But it gives  `NULL` in `LOCATION1` and `LOCATION2`

Answer (score 1):

You will have to join it two times to get the desired result because you are expecting two additional columns in your result.

```
df1.show()
+----+---------+
| PIN| LOCATION|
+----+---------+
|1234|  Germany|
|2356|   Poland|
|2894|  England|
|3452|Bloomberg|
+----+---------+

df2.show()
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+

df2.join(df1, df2.STARTLOCATION==df1.PIN)\
    .withColumnRenamed("LOCATION", "LOCATION1")\
    .drop("PIN")\
    .join(df1, df2.ENDLOCATION==df1.PIN)\
    .withColumnRenamed("LOCATION", "LOCATION2")\
    .drop("PIN")\
    .show()
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION|LOCATION1|LOCATION2|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|Bloomberg|  England|
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|  Germany|  England|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|   Poland|  Germany|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using sql statement to achieve it, you can try:

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp1')
df2.createOrReplaceTempView('tmp2')
sql = """
    select a.MAIL,a.STARTLOCATION,a.ENDLOCATION,b.LOCATION as LOCATION1,c.LOCATION as LOCATION2
    from tmp2 a join tmp1 b on a.STARTLOCATION=b.PIN
        join tmp1 c on a.ENDLOCATION=c.PIN
"""
df = spark.sql(sql)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pyspark

import findspark
findspark.init()

import pyspark
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.functions import *
from pyspark.sql.types import*
import pandas as pd
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("Test").getOrCreate()

df1=spark.createDataFrame([Row(PIN=1234, LOCATION='Germany'),Row(PIN=2356, LOCATION='Poland'), Row(PIN=2894, LOCATION='England'),Row(PIN=3452, LOCATION='Bloomberg')])

df1.show()
+----+---------+
| PIN| LOCATION|
+----+---------+
|1234|  Germany|
|2356|   Poland|
|2894|  England|
|3452|Bloomberg|
+----+---------+

df2=spark.createDataFrame([Row(MAIL='ami@test.com',STARTLOCATION=1234, ENDLOCATION=2894), Row(MAIL='asd@test.com',STARTLOCATION=2356, ENDLOCATION=1234),Row(MAIL='cddv@test.com',STARTLOCATION=3452, ENDLOCATION=2894)])

df2.show()

+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+

df3= df2.join(df1, df1['PIN']==df2['STARTLOCATION'], 'inner')

df3.show()

+-------------+-------------+-----------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+

df3= df2.join(df1, df1['PIN']==df2['STARTLOCATION'], 'inner')

df3.show()

+-------------+-------------+-----------+----+---------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION| PIN| LOCATION|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----+---------+
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|3452|Bloomberg|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|2356|   Poland|
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|1234|  Germany|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+----+---------+

df4=df3.drop('PIN')
df5=df4.withColumnRenamed('LOCATION', 'LOCATION1')
df5.show()

df6=df5.join(df1, df1['PIN']==df5['ENDLOCATION'], 'inner')

final=df6.withColumnRenamed("LOCATION", "LOCATION2").drop('PIN')
final.show()

+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|         MAIL|STARTLOCATION|ENDLOCATION|LOCATION1|LOCATION2|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
|cddv@test.com|         3452|       2894|Bloomberg|  England|
| ami@test.com|         1234|       2894|  Germany|  England|
| asd@test.com|         2356|       1234|   Poland|  Germany|
+-------------+-------------+-----------+---------+---------+
```